# How to Implement? When User Sign In using SAML, ADFS response with successful authentication, but I also need to check Identity User table

Tags: c#, .net, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

SSO has been working fine with my application using ITFoxtec. A new requirement of my app is to also check the user in the Identity.User table (Identity in .Net6). If the user is not in the User table or user has been marked as a Deleted user in the table, even if ADFS returns a successful authentication result, I want to deny user from accessing the app. How to implement this please? Thanks

I'm thinking to add addtional steps in AssertionConsumerService, considering it before the saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user is valid in the [`ClaimsTransform.Transform`](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Identity/ClaimsTransform.cs#L20) method and throw an exception if invalid. Then the session is never created in the [`saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession`](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L59) method.